# SQL seems to round up the number automatically on select statement?

Tags: sql

Hi Here is my SQL code:

```
    SELECT a."Date", a."Missed", b."Total Client Schedules", cast(100-((a."Missed"*100) / b."Total Client Schedules")AS decimal) as "Pct Completed" -
  FROM -
   ( -
     SELECT DATE(scheduled_start) as "Date",count(*) as "Missed" FROM -
     events WHERE node_name IS NOT NULL AND status IN ('Missed') GROUP BY DATE(scheduled_start) -
    ) as a, -
   ( -
    SELECT DATE(scheduled_start) as "Date", count(*) as -
    "Total Client Schedules" FROM events WHERE node_name IS NOT NULL GROUP BY DATE(scheduled_start) -
    ) as b -
  WHERE a."Date" = b."Date" ORDER BY "Date" desc
```

and Here is the output

```
       Date           Missed      Total Client Schedules      Pct Completed
-----------     ------------     -----------------------     --------------
 2013-02-20                2                         805                100
 2013-02-19               14                         805                 99
 2013-02-18               29                         805                 97
 2013-02-17               59                         805                 93
 2013-02-16               29                         806                 97
 2013-02-15               49                         805                 94
 2013-02-14               33                         805                 96
 2013-02-13               57                         805                 93
 2013-02-12               21                         805                 98
 2013-02-11               35                         805                 96
 2013-02-10               34                         805                 96
```

it always seems to round to the highest number when i want it to be like 99.99% or 97.2% etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what database you are using.  However, some databases do integer arithmetic, so 1/2 is 0 not 0.5.

To fix this, just make the constants you are using numeric rather than integer:

```
cast(100.0-((a."Missed"*100.0) / b."Total Client Schedules")AS decimal)
```

It will then convert to a non-integer type for the arithmetic.

Comment: that doesnt appear to have worked. i am using the IBM TSM database so this may not be possible then :(

Comment: ok it has worked now i changed it to round(100.0-((a."Missed"*100.0) / b."Total Client Schedules"),2)

Comment: But the number now displays as 99.75000000000000000 so i just need to get rid of all the 0's :D

Comment: Try something like as `decimal(6, 2)` for the cast.